# How to assign data returned from function to $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my code,

```
$scope.output=abc(1,2);
    function abc(mid, type) {
       $http({
               ...
             }
           }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
          }, function (response) {
         });
      }
    console.log($scope.output)
```

> $scope.output

is

> undefined

Function is executing but data is not assigning to $scope variable

Answer (score 1):

```
abc(1,2);
function abc(mid, type) {
   $http({
           ...
         }
       }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.output = response.data;

      }, function (response) {
     });
  }
console.log($scope.output)
```

In async operations, you cannot use return

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `return` in `async call`. You can directly assign the response.data into the `$scope.output` variable.

```
abc(1,2);
function abc(mid, type) {
   $http({
           ...
         }
       }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.output = response.data;
      }, function(error) {
     });
  }
```